# Animate a circle - how to?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, adobe-animate

I'd like to animate a circle like here http://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/ using a design tool, not code.
I tried with Animate CC and After Effects but can't get ahead of it.

The output shall be used in web and have several other elements to be animated and combined.  (so it's not only that part of the animation but also several others, so I can't actually use the linked js-animation therefore)

This is the image, and I guess you can thereby estimate what I want: 4 times an effect with that circle opening up. Each after each other:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know how you’d like to use it on the web page? A GIF? A video file? An SVG animation? Do you need to animate arbitrary graphs, or just one? Those answers will likely dictate the best method.

Answer (score 1):

For after effects you want to use the effect `radial wipe`. It does exactly what is at that link. Premiere pro has it as well. Other editing and video programs also have it.

You sent your center point on the object (it doesn't have to be a circle) and animate the transition completion.